# angular2 $routeChangeStart , $routeChangeSuccess ,$routeChangeError

Tags: angular

In angular2 what is the equivalent of these angular1 events?

$routeChangeStart  , $routeChangeSuccess  ,$routeChangeError

I want to use these events in root app component to deal with any route changing.

thanks in advance

**update**

- If i use OnActivate, OnDeactivate  events, it needs to add it to every component :(
- Also i tried to implement my own RouterOutlet but i can't access previous instruction on activate, deactivate events, also i don't know how to handle the route Change Error
- Also router.subscribe gave me the name only but i want to get the current and next instruction objects to change some properties

My target is:

1- Show loading indicator when start change page and hide it on page load.

2- Make transition animation rtl or ltr for current and next instruction

Comment: i solve the problem

for any one face this problem , you can make your own RouterOutlet directive which inherit from RouterOutlet then use it as a proxy

Comment: Have you some sample? any plunkr?

Comment: @JavierRos there are some posts & projects if you search for *angular2 custom router outlet*. Some of those are from [captaincoder](http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/), [auth0](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts), [blacksonic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331478/angular2-redirect-to-login-page/35817366#35817366)

Answer (score 3):

There are some events such as `OnActivate`, `OnDeactivate` and guard functions `CanActivate` and `CanDeactivate` that you can look at.

See the documentation for [Router](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/)

Comment: these events work in component level , i want to cover all route changing in root app component
,
i want to cover <router-outlet>  change in root app component

Comment: The component hooks are different https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/lifecycle_hooks/

Comment: thanks Chandermani for trying to help me
i read  component hooks but it's help us for watching changing values of properties (any property)  but route not a property

Comment: i can deal with route location as property but it will not catch all routing events like $routeChangeSuccess ,$routeChangeError , it will not deal with routing as a routing but only as a property

Comment: - if i use OnActivate, OnDeactivate  events , but it need to add it to every component  :(

- also i tried to implement my own RouterOutlet but i can't access previous instruction on activate , deactivate events, also i couldn't know how to handle route Change Error

-also router.subscribe gave me the name only , but i want to get the current and next instruction objects to change some properties 
 
my target is:
1- show loading indicator when start change page , and hide it when finish change page.
2- make  transition animation rtl or ltr for current and next instruction

Comment: i solve the problem

for any one face this problem , you can make your own RouterOutlet directive which inherit from RouterOutlet then use it as a proxy

Answer (score 2):

i solved the problem, for any one who face this problem , you can make your own RouterOutlet directive which inherit from RouterOutlet then use it as a proxy