# What is the Angular2 equivalent to an AngularJS $routeChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, events, routes

In `AngularJS` we were able to specify route change event to observe changes in route object using the `$routeChangeStart/End` event of the `$rootScope`. What is the equivalent of the route change event in Angular2?

---

how can we do this exact functionality of below code in Angular2

```
 $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
        //do what you want
      });
```

I got some disucussions here, But it don't have more details, So I asked a new question.

[angular2 $routeChangeStart , $routeChangeSuccess ,$routeChangeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542264/angular2-routechangestart-routechangesuccess-routechangeerror)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen the events of the router by doing the following:

```
import {
  Router, ActivatedRoute,
  NavigationEnd, NavigationStart,
  NavigationError, NavigationCancel,
} from '@angular/router';

// constructor method of some angular element
constructor(
    private _router: Router,
  ) {
this._router.events
          .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
          .subscribe(event => {
            console.log("New route");
          });
 }
```

EDIT: Im not completely sure is that is actually what you need, after taking a closer look to the angularjs docs seems like those events are more related to the resolution/result of a guard in angular2

Comment: also, you should enable events in the RouterModule.forRoot

Comment: what do you mean? enableTracing?

Comment: Not necessary, the events are triggered independent of that flag. That only logs the events information in the console

Comment: ah, yeah, got confused :)

Comment: when this method will be hit? routchangestart or end?

Comment: The Router element emits a new event of type NavigationStart every time that the user try to navigates to a new route. NavigationEnd is emitted when the new route is valid. The docs are pretty clear, check them out :)